# Broken URL from wysiwyg shortcodes on category and product pages on Magento

Tags: php, magento, wysiwyg

Broken Links from wysiwyg on frontend of Magento store. Am unsure what has caused this but they were working previously.

My Urls created from Wysiwyg seem to be fine within admin and are only broken on category and product pages however they still seem to be working on CMS Pages.

The URL's on broken pages are not like below with broken shortcodes:

Admin -

```
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/image.png"}}" alt="image" />
```

Frontend -

```
    <img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" image.png"}}"="" alt="image">
```

These img tags have been inserted into different attributes within admin of Magento where wysywig has been used for adding images.

On the product view page there are sometimes the {{media url=""}} pulled from the description attribute in products. On category view pages they also sometimes appear in description attribute of categories. I think its just going into the description block but my templates are modified from default.

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue with quotes. You should use this code.

```
<img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/image.png'}}" alt="image" />

Now you can use below code to get proper image output.

<?php
    echo $this->helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product,nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description'));
 ?>
```

Hope this code helps you!!!

Comment: I have tried it with single quotes in the middle but this does not fix it.

Comment: Also I have not messed with any of the img elements recently ( they were all working perfectly) and all seemed to have broken at the same time randomly but only on category and product pages leading me to believe its an issue with how this media tag is not being processed properly under these conditions.

Comment: Let me know proper description. Do you want that image at product detail page or list page?? and also tell me from where you are trying to get that image, i mean from static block or product description block??

Comment: These are in different attributes, on the product view page there are sometimes the {{media url=""}} pulled from the description attribute in products. On category view pages they also sometimes appear in description attribute of categories where wysywig has been used for adding images. I think its just going into the description block but my templates are modified from default.

Comment: Now Try this one
$html =  Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($content);

Comment: I'm unsure where or how to use this on a category or product template however? Do i need to process each attribute or is there a whole output somewhere deeper?

Comment: Just replace your block data with **$content** and echo **$html**

Comment: So am unsure still so i just replaced the code for description like so but still didn't work:     <?php $content = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description');
                               echo  $html = Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($content); ?>

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly caused by the new security permissions added with security patch 6788 or from upgrading to 1.9.2.2+

Solution might be to **add the variable to the permissions list** in

> System -> Permissions -> Variables.